# Java program that display sequence of 5 even numbers starting from the input number

Tags: java, loops

I need a java program that will print a sequence of 5 even numbers starting from the input number.

The output should be : `2 4 6 8 10`

But when I input 4 the output was : 4 6 8 but it should be: 4 6 8 10 12
how to set a sequence of 5 even numbers starting from the input.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3InHP.png)

So far this is my code:

```
    int sum = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter number:");

    int num = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    if (num % 2 == 0) {
        for (int x = num; x <= 6; x++) // HERE
        {
            System.out.print(num + " ");
            sum = sum + num;
            num = num + 2;
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Sum is " + sum);
    }
```

It would help me a lot. thanks in advance!

Comment: `for (int x=num; x<=6;x++)` -> `for (int x=0; x<=4;x++)`

Comment: the logic of the question seems off -- what's the expected behavior if the user keys in an odd number?

Comment: actually the whole problem was when you entered even number the output should be sequence of 5 numbers and when you entered odd number the output should be a sequence of 10 numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to loop 5 times, so consider

```
    int num= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    if (num%2 == 0)
    {
        for (int x=0; x < 5;x++) 
        {    
          System.out.print(num + " ");
          num=num+2;
        }
    }
```

Based upon your comment (loop for 10 for odd) so could do

```
    int num= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    int loopTo = 10;
    if (num%2 == 0)
    {
       loopTo = 5;
    }

     for (int x=0; x < loopTo;x++) 
     {    
          System.out.print(num + " ");
          num=num+2;
     }
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much. This is what I am looking for :)

Comment: Glad to hear.  Please consider to upvote/accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Enter number: ");
int num= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
int loopTo = 0;
int sum = 0;
if (num%2 == 0)
{
   loopTo = 5;
 for (int x=0; x < loopTo;x++) 
 {    
      System.out.print(num + " ");
      sum=sum+num;
      num=num+2;
 }
}
else if (num%2!=0)
 {
     loopTo=10;
  for (int x=0; x < loopTo;x++) 
  {    
       System.out.print(num + " ");
       sum=sum+num;
       num=num+1;
  }
 }
 System.out.println("");
 System.out.println("Sum is "+ sum);
```

Gotcha! This is what I needed. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: The answer was given by @Scary Wombat,  an hour before you are posting yours. You need to appreciate and acknowledge people's efforts.

Comment: Yeah I did it. I just posted the whole program for future references.